# Сортировка двумерного массива по 1 элементу

Tags: python

Пытаюсь отсортировать двумерный массив по второму элементу по цифрам от большего к меньшего. Но в ответ получаю какую-то фигню. Оно то работает, то нет. Случайность какая-то.
Видимо, я делаю, что-то не так. Пожалуйсто, укажите на мою ошибку и, если это Вас не затруднит, пришлите свой вариант.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: смотрю и удивляюсь, "хочу отсортировать массив" - massiv=SORTIRUI,SUKA и POKAJI , какое-то страное оно - программирование высокоуровневое

Comment: Эта фича только показывает? А почему тогда после этого элементы в моем массиве меняются местами?

Comment: понятия не имею что она делает, я питон первый раз вижу. Просто по названиям функций вижу что это такое

Comment: Уважаемый Лёня, у меня к вам просьба как-то подбирать лексикон. Это не анимешный форум, все-таки.

Comment: Причём тут анимешный форум и мой лексикон? Лучше бы вопрос прочитали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-умолчанию сортируются непосредственно сами элементы массива, в вашем случае -- массивы. Если сортировать надо по определённому параметру элемента, то необходимо передать в основанный параметр `key` функцию, возвращающую нужный параметр, в вашем случае -- второй элемент массива. Её можно определить как обычную функцию через `def` либо как лямбда-выражение, как в моём примере.

```py
arr = [['asd', 4], ['fgh', 5], ['jkl', 3]]
print(arr)
arr.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
print(arr)
```

Вывод:

```
[['asd', 4], ['fgh', 5], ['jkl', 3]]
[['jkl', 3], ['asd', 4], ['fgh', 5]]
```